# Select all records in which at least n-1 of n criteria has been matched

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12c. I'm wondering if it is possible to select all records in which n-1 of n criteria has been matched ?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(id number, 
firstname varchar2(100), 
lastname varchar2(100), 
city  varchar2(100));

insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, city)
 values (1, 'John', 'Smith', 'London');
insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, city)
 values (2, 'Tom',  'Smith', 'London');
insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, city)
 values (3, 'John', 'Davis', 'London');
insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, city)
 values (4, 'John', 'Smith', 'Bristol');
insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, city)
 values (5, 'Tom',  'Davis', 'London');
insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, city)
 values (6, 'Tom',  'Davis', 'Bristol');

 select * from users 
  where firstname = 'John' 
    and lastname = 'Smith'
    and city= 'London'
```

This select will return only one record that match all three criteria (id = 1). What I need is a query that returns all the records that match at least two of three criteria (id = 1, 2, 3, 4).

Is it possible in Oracle if we know that users table has 5 milions records ?

Comment: Side note: Thank you for providing INSERT statements and a correct query you needed help with. To make it even more helpful, you should also include a CREATE TABLE statement; and the INSERT statements should be tested. (The INSERT statement you posted is invalid in Oracle; you should test it, then keep fixing it until it works correctly.)

Comment: "Is it possible in Oracle if we know that users table has 5 milions records?"  Its possible, yes, but what kind of performance do you need?  I'm assuming you want implement a loose matching logic using just SQL, and your example is overly simplified.  I'd suggest to look into [Solr indexes](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Select 1 for each column that passes, 0 otherwise, sum it up and compare to number of columns.

Answer (score 21):

General approach is to put each condition in a `CASE` returning 1 or 0, and count the number of 1s:

```
select * from users 
where (CASE WHEN firstname = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN lastname = 'Smith' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN city= 'London' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2
```

Each matching condition contributes 1 to the sum, so you can check how many conditions have been satisfied.

Answer (score 9):

You can use expressions in the where clause:

```
select *
from users 
where ( (case when firstname = 'John' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when lastname = 'Smith' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when city = 'London' then 1 else 0 end)
      ) = 2;
```

This generalizes easily, but for 3 conditions and 2 matches, it is easy enough to do:

```
where (firstname = 'John' and lastname = 'Smith' and city <> 'London') or
      (firstname = 'John' and lastname <> 'Smith' and city = 'London') or
      (firstname <> 'John' and lastname = 'Smith' and city = 'London')
```

However, this doesn't general very nicely.

Comment: I was thinking about first solution but do you think that this will work effectively for 5 millions records ?

Comment: @pieniak . . . Either version should have similar performance.  A full table scan seems necessary.  Well, there might be ways to optimize the performance in Oracle, using the second version and the right indexes.

Comment: The OP said *at least* two conditions should be satisfied; you wrote it for *exactly* two. Which may also cause a problem for the second solution, if some of the columns are nullable: for example John-Smith-London should presumably match John-Smith-NULL, but your second version will reject it. In fact in this case the two solutions are not equivalent.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I read the question as:  "I'm wondering if it is possible to select all records in which n-1 of n criteria has been matched ?"  Obviously, for more conditions, `>=` can be substituted for `=`.

Answer (score 5):

If you run queries like this one often (possibly for different inputs for the `firstname`, `lastname` and `city` you need to match), and you need to prioritize the performance of these queries over other queries (and over the performance of DML statements), you could create three composite indexes: on `(firstname, lastname)`, on `(firstname, city)` and on `(lastname, city)`.

Then the query should be a UNION ALL. It will read data three times instead of a single pass - but it will read from the indexes, resulting in much faster performance as long as only a small fraction of rows matches on each of the three conditions. Then only a small fraction of the 5 million rows will be actually read from disk in their entirety.

```
select * from users where firstname = 'John' and lastname = 'Smith'
UNION ALL
select * from users where firstname = 'John' and city = 'London'
                          and (lastname  != 'Smith' or lastname  is null)
UNION ALL
select * from users where lastname = 'Smith' and city = 'London'
                          and (firstname != 'John'  or firstname is null)
;
```

You may change the strings to match to bind variables, so that `'John'`, `'Smith'` and `'London'` (or other values!) are supplied at runtime instead of being hard-coded into the query.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dynamic set of filters that you need to pass into the query then you can `UNPIVOT` the data and filter the values and then `GROUP BY id` and use `HAVING` to ensure that at least the correct number of filters are matched:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf52b/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id, firstname, lastname, city) AS
  SELECT 1, 'John', 'Smith', 'London'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Tom',  'Smith', 'London'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'John', 'Davis', 'London'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'John', 'Smith', 'Bristol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Tom',  'Davis', 'London'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Tom',  'Davis', 'Bristol' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH filters ( key, value ) AS (
  SELECT 'FIRSTNAME', 'John'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LASTNAME',  'Smith'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CITY',      'London' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id
FROM   users
UNPIVOT( value FOR key IN ( firstname, lastname, city ) ) kv
INNER JOIN filters f
ON ( f.key = kv.key AND f.value = kv.value )
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf52b/3/0)**:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  4 |
|  3 |
```

If you want to get all the columns then you can join it back to the original table.

Comment: Or to keep it flexible: `HAVING COUNT(*) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM filters)` ?

Comment: @AlexPoole - You can't keep it flexible in the way you suggest. You may change the firstname, lastname and city **values** you want to match - that's the flexibility, don't hard-code them in the query; but *which* columns you need to match (and in particular the number of such columns) is set in stone. Otherwise you must use dynamic SQL, and that doesn't seem to be what MT0 meant here.

Comment: This approach will result in much worse performance. The data as presented is already grouped by id; by unpivoting it, you are losing all that information - only to have to group again (a much more expensive operation compared to the rest). You can make the query more flexible, in the spirit of what you were trying here, by letting the `filters` CTE be one row and three columns, matching the OP's rowtype (minus the id). Although, obviously, the best approach is to use bind variables rather than a WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

With this query (exactly describing the possible matches)

```
select * from users 
where (firstname = 'John' and lastname = 'Smith' ) or
      (firstname = 'John' and  city = 'London') or
      (lastname = 'Smith' and city = 'London')
```

assuming the three columns has defined indexes, you may expect a concatenated index access consisting of three INDEX ACCESS operation.

You may even define a two column index covering your match options:

```
create index users_idx1 on users (lastname,firstname);
create index users_idx2 on users (lastname,city);
create index users_idx3 on users (city,firstname );
```

This leads to following execution plan

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |            |    33 |  5577 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  CONCATENATION               |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS      |    11 |  1859 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | USERS_IDX3 |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS      |    11 |  1859 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | USERS_IDX3 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS      |    11 |  1859 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | USERS_IDX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("LASTNAME"='Smith')
   3 - access("CITY"='London')
   4 - filter(LNNVL("LASTNAME"='Smith') OR LNNVL("CITY"='London'))
   5 - access("CITY"='London' AND "FIRSTNAME"='John')
   6 - filter((LNNVL("FIRSTNAME"='John') OR LNNVL("CITY"='London')) AND 
              (LNNVL("LASTNAME"='Smith') OR LNNVL("CITY"='London')))
   7 - access("LASTNAME"='Smith' AND "FIRSTNAME"='John')
```

Notice that the access in lines 7 and 5 uses predicate on both columns, the access in line 3 only the city- You'll have to adjust the index definition according to your data cardinalities if this is a performance problem.

You may also check, if the [Oracle Text Index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#g1020588) is not the option you are missing.